# How are generators implemented?

Tags: implementation, generators

Several languages, such as JavaScript, C#, and Python, have "generator" methods that lazily yield a series of values rather than returning a single one:

```js
function* upToThree() {
  for (let i = 1; i < 3; ++i) {
    console.log(`In generator, i = ${i}`);
    yield i;
  }
}

let g = upToThree();
console.log('Before the loop');
for (const el of g)
  console.log(`In loop, got ${el}`);

/* Console:
Before the loop
In generator, i = 1
In loop, got 1
In generator, i = 2
In loop, got 2
*/
```

While this feature is convenient to have, it's not obvious how to implement them, especially in a compiled language: local variables can't necessarily be stored on the stack, as the generator could be partially iterated and then passed somewhere else.

What are some strategies for implementing generators?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible method, which is what babel does in javascript, is to have a struct containing the current position in the generator then a switch case like construct to be able to start the function in the middle. For example, this:

```c
generator fib() {
    a, b = 1, 2
    while (a<100) {
        b, a = a, a+b
        yield a
    }
    yield a-1
}
```

can be converted into:

```c
struct fibState {
    a,
    b,
    position
}

int fib(fibState state) {
    switch (fibState.postion) {
        case 0:
            fibState.a, fibState.b = 1,2
            while (a<100) {
                fibState.b, fibState.a = fibState.a, fibState.a+fibState.b
                // switching the context
                fibState.position = 1;
                return fibState.a;
        case 1:
            }

            fibState.position = 2;
            return fibState.a-1
        case 2:
            fibState.position = -1;
    }
}
```

Yes, C allows you to interleave switch case and loops like that.

Basically, we use a switch case in this case to act as a goto, and allow us to immediately jump to the part of the function we left off. We have a struct which contains all our local variables, and also a variable that tells us where to jump to next time the generator is resumed.

In real assembly the entire switch case and looping construct would be compiled down to `goto`s.