# How are coroutines implemented in a tree-walking interpreter?

Tags: implementation, iterators, generators, coroutines, tree-walker

It seems to me that coroutines and derived abstractions like the iterators and generators are implemented the following way:

- When returning

  1. Move the function's stack frame to the heap
  2. Save a pointer to the exact instruction that the function was executing
- When resuming

  1. Reactivate the stack frame
  2. Jump to the saved instruction pointer

This makes sense to me but deals with a linear code structure which implies a bytecode interpreter. How does it work in a tree-walking interpreter?

```lisp
(a (b (c (yield))))
```

I was not able to find any example code to study. All popular programming languages apparently use bytecode interpreters which work as I described above. I also found [this question](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/q/820/2098) but the answer seems to be conceptually the same as the linear jump case, only using `switch` instead.

So how would one implement coroutines in a tree-walking interpreter? How can progress through the evaluation of an expression tree be saved?

Comment: The simplest answer is meta-circularly: make the "eval" function a coroutine, which yields when the interpreted code yields.

Comment: You might want to check out the chapter on streams in SICP.

Comment: If the language has closures, you can use the same mechanism you use to save the bindings of a closure.

Comment: To expand on @kaya3's excellent comment: I'll note that "save the execution environment somewhere and make a note of the instruction to resume on later" is also how "normal" (non-co-call) calls work. You're just used to working in languages where you get that "for free". What if you didn't? It's character-building to consider what mechanisms you'd have to build to bootstrap interpreting language with subroutines in a language that lacked them.

Answer (score 2):

If you express your interpreter in [continuation-passing style](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style), then the continuation of evaluating one node in your expression tree represents the same information as a recursive stack frame, but instead stored as a closure. Coroutine `suspend` is then an expression that returns a value that will call the continuation when you `resume` it, instead of evaluating the continuation immediately.

Here is an implementation in Rust, for example:

```rust
#![feature(trait_alias)]

use core::fmt::{Debug, Formatter};
impl Debug for Value {
    fn fmt(&self, fmt: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> Result<(), std::fmt::Error> {
        match self {
            Value::Number(u) => write!(fmt, "{}", u),
            Value::Coroutine(c) => write!(fmt, "<coroutine>"),
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Expr {
    Number(usize),
    Add(Box<Expr>, Box<Expr>),
    Suspend,
    Resume(Box<Expr>, Box<Expr>),
}

trait Cont = FnOnce(Value) -> Value;

enum Value {
    Number(usize),
    Coroutine(Box<dyn Cont>),
}


fn eval(e: Expr, cont: Box<dyn Cont>) -> Value {
    println!("{:?}", e);
    match e {
        Expr::Number(u) => cont(Value::Number(u)),
        Expr::Add(l, r) => {
            cont(eval(*l, Box::new(|l_val| {
                if let Value::Number(l_num) = l_val {
                    eval(*r, Box::new(move |r_val| {
                        if let Value::Number(r_num) = r_val {
                            Value::Number(l_num + r_num)
                        } else {
                            panic!("can't add non-number right operand");
                        }
                    }))
                } else {
                    panic!("can't add non-number left operand");
                }
            })))
        },
        Expr::Suspend => {
            Value::Coroutine(Box::new(|v| cont(v)))
        },
        Expr::Resume(c, r) => {
            cont(eval(*c, Box::new(|coro_val| {
                if let Value::Coroutine(coro) = coro_val {
                    eval(*r, Box::new(|r_val| {
                        coro(r_val)
                    }))
                } else {
                    panic!("can't resume non-coroutine");
                }
            })))
        }
    }
}


fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", eval(Expr::Add(
        Box::new(Expr::Number(1)),
        Box::new(Expr::Number(2))),
        Box::new(|v| v)));
    println!("{:?}", eval(Expr::Resume(
        Box::new(Expr::Add(
            Box::new(Expr::Suspend),
            Box::new(Expr::Number(2)))),
        Box::new(Expr::Number(1))),
            Box::new(|v| v)));
    println!("{:?}", eval(Expr::Resume(
        Box::new(Expr::Add(
            Box::new(Expr::Number(1)),
            Box::new(Expr::Suspend))),
        Box::new(Expr::Number(2))),
            Box::new(|v| v)));
}
```